# Audio is MUTE in playing while Decoding Video and Audio streams from a Video File

Tags: android, decode, playback, decoding, android-mediacodec

I am using two MediaCodec to decode video and audio streams. My final goal is to generate a new video file (.mp4 or .wmv file) after adjusting or changing audio. 
Right now, i am just testing how to decode video and audio from a .wmv video file while playback.

**The problem that I am having now is that the video file is playing by using MediaPlayer while decoding video and audio streams, but there is no sound.**

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

**Here is what I have tried so far.**

**DecodingActivity.java (SurfaceView in activity_decoding.xml)**

```
public class DecodingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{

    private static final String TAG = "DecodingActivity";

    private static final String FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.mp4";

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    private VideoDecoderThread mVideoDecoder;
    private AudioDecoderThread mAudioDecoder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_decoding);

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(DecodingActivity.this);

        mVideoDecoder = new VideoDecoderThread();
        mAudioDecoder = new AudioDecoderThread();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(FILE_PATH);
            //mMediaPlayer.prepare(); // this causes IllegalException Error

            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(DecodingActivity.this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        Log.d(TAG,"mAudioDecoder: "+mAudioDecoder);
        Log.d(TAG,"mVideoDecoder: "+mVideoDecoder);

        if (mVideoDecoder != null && mAudioDecoder != null) {
            if (mVideoDecoder.init(holder.getSurface(), FILE_PATH)) {
                mVideoDecoder.start();
                mAudioDecoder.startPlay(FILE_PATH); 
            } else {
                mVideoDecoder = null;
                mAudioDecoder = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mVideoDecoder != null) {
            mVideoDecoder.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAudioDecoder.stop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**AudioDecoderThread.java**

```
public class AudioDecoderThread {

    private static final String TAG = "AudioDecoder";

    private static final int TIMEOUT_US = 1000;
    private MediaExtractor mExtractor;
    private MediaCodec mDecoder;

    private boolean eosReceived;
    private int mSampleRate = 0;

    /**
     * 
     * @param
     */
    public void startPlay(String path) {
        eosReceived = false;
        mExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
        try {
            mExtractor.setDataSource(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int channel = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mExtractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
            MediaFormat format = mExtractor.getTrackFormat(i);
            String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            if (mime.startsWith("audio/")) {

                mExtractor.selectTrack(i);
                Log.d(TAG, "format : " + format);
                //{aac-profile=2, mime=audio/mp4a-latm, channel-count=2, max-input-size=1572864, isDMCMMExtractor=1, durationUs=35526530, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=2,capacity=2], encoder-delay=2112, encoder-padding=588, sample-rate=44100}

                ByteBuffer csd = format.getByteBuffer("csd-0"); //csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=2,capacity=2]

                for (int k = 0; k < csd.capacity(); ++k) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "csd : " + csd.array()[k]);
                }
                mSampleRate = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);
                channel = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT);

                Log.d(TAG, "mSampleRate : " + mSampleRate); // 44100
                Log.d(TAG, "channel : " + channel); // 2

                break;
            }
        }
        MediaFormat format = makeAACCodecSpecificData(MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC, mSampleRate, channel);

        Log.d(TAG, "format[MediaFormat]: " + format);
        if (format == null)
            return;

        try {
            mDecoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mDecoder.configure(format, null, null, 0);

        if (mDecoder == null) {
            Log.e("DecodeActivity", "Can't find video info!");
            return;
        }

        mDecoder.start(); 

        new Thread(AACDecoderAndPlayRunnable).start();
    }

    /**
     * The code profile, Sample rate, channel Count is used to
     * produce the AAC Codec SpecificData.
     * Android 4.4.2/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/avc_utils.cpp refer
     * to the portion of the code written.
     * 
     * MPEG-4 Audio refer : http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=MPEG-4_Audio#Audio_Specific_Config
     * 
     * @param audioProfile is MPEG-4 Audio Object Types
     * @param sampleRate
     * @param channelConfig
     * @return MediaFormat
     */
    private MediaFormat makeAACCodecSpecificData(int audioProfile, int sampleRate, int channelConfig) {

        MediaFormat format = new MediaFormat();
        format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm"); 
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, sampleRate); 
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, channelConfig);

        int samplingFreq[] = {
            96000, 88200, 64000, 48000, 44100, 32000, 24000, 22050,
            16000, 12000, 11025, 8000
        };

        int sampleIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < samplingFreq.length; ++i) {
            if (samplingFreq[i] == sampleRate) {
                Log.d(TAG, "kSamplingFreq " + samplingFreq[i] + " i : " + i); // kSamplingFreq 44100 i : 4
                sampleIndex = i;
            }
        }

        if (sampleIndex == -1) {
            return null;
        }

        ByteBuffer csd = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);

        csd.put((byte) ((audioProfile << 3) | (sampleIndex >> 1)));

        csd.position(1);

        csd.put((byte) ((byte) ((sampleIndex << 7) & 0x80) | (channelConfig << 3)));
        csd.flip();

        format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", csd); // add csd-0

        for (int k = 0; k < csd.capacity(); ++k) {
            Log.e(TAG, "csd : " + csd.array()[k]);
        }

        return format;
    }

    Runnable AACDecoderAndPlayRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            AACDecoderAndPlay();
        }
    };

    /**
     * After decoding AAC, Play using Audio Track.
     */
    public void AACDecoderAndPlay() {

        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mDecoder.getInputBuffers();
        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mDecoder.getOutputBuffers();

        Log.d(TAG, "inputBuffers: "+inputBuffers);
        Log.d(TAG, "outputBuffers: "+outputBuffers);

        BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();

        int buffsize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(mSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        Log.d(TAG, "buffsize: "+buffsize); // 14176

        AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mSampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                buffsize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        //Log.d(TAG, "audioTrack: "+audioTrack); //android.media.AudioTrack@4be0ac7

        audioTrack.play();

        Log.d(TAG, "------------------------------------------------: ");

        while (!eosReceived) {
            int inIndex = mDecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_US); // 버퍼 index
            Log.d(TAG, "inIndex: "+inIndex);

            if (inIndex > -1) {
                ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
                int sampleSize = mExtractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
                Log.d(TAG, "buffer: "+buffer);
                Log.d(TAG, "sampleSize: "+sampleSize);
                if (sampleSize < 0) {
                    // We shouldn't stop the playback at this point, just pass the EOS
                    // flag to mDecoder, we will get it again from the
                    // dequeueOutputBuffer
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                    mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);

                } else {
                    mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, mExtractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                    mExtractor.advance();
                }

                int outIndex = mDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_US);
                Log.d(TAG, "outIndex: "+outIndex);

                switch (outIndex) { // outputBufferIndex
                case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED: 
                    Log.d(TAG, "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                    outputBuffers = mDecoder.getOutputBuffers();
                    break;

                case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                    MediaFormat format = mDecoder.getOutputFormat();
                    Log.d(TAG, "New format " + format);
                    audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE));

                    break;
                case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER: 
                    Log.d(TAG, "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
                    break;

                default: 
                    ByteBuffer outBuffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];
                    Log.v(TAG, "We can't use this buffer but render it due to the API limit, " + outBuffer);

                    final byte[] chunk = new byte[info.size];
                    outBuffer.get(chunk); // Read the buffer all at once
                    outBuffer.clear(); // ** MUST DO!!! OTHERWISE THE NEXT TIME YOU GET THIS SAME BUFFER BAD THINGS WILL HAPPEN

                    audioTrack.write(chunk, info.offset, info.offset + info.size); // AudioTrack write data
                    mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, false);
                    break;
                }

                // All decoded frames have been rendered, we can stop playing now
                if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "OutputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        mDecoder.stop();
        mDecoder.release();
        mDecoder = null;

        mExtractor.release();
        mExtractor = null;

        audioTrack.stop();
        audioTrack.release();
        audioTrack = null;
    }

    public void stop() {
        eosReceived = true;
    }

}
```

**VideoDecoderThread.java**

```
public class VideoDecoderThread extends Thread {

    private static final String VIDEO = "video/";
    private static final String TAG = "VideoDecoder";

    private MediaExtractor mExtractor;
    private MediaCodec mDecoder;

    private boolean eosReceived;


    public boolean init(Surface surface, String filePath) {
        eosReceived = false;
        try {
            mExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
            mExtractor.setDataSource(filePath);

            for (int i = 0; i < mExtractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
                MediaFormat format = mExtractor.getTrackFormat(i);

                String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
                Log.d(TAG, "mime : " + mime); // video/avc

                if (mime.startsWith(VIDEO)) { 
                    mExtractor.selectTrack(i);
                    mDecoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime); 
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "format : " + format);

                        mDecoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0 /* Decoder */); 

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "codec '" + mime + "' failed configuration. " + e);
                        return false;
                    }

                    mDecoder.start(); 
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();

        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mDecoder.getInputBuffers();
        mDecoder.getOutputBuffers();
        //Log.d(TAG, "mDecoder.getInputBuffers(); : " + mDecoder.getInputBuffers()); 
        //Log.d(TAG, "mDecoder.getOutputBuffers(); : " + mDecoder.getOutputBuffers()); 

        boolean isInput = true;
        boolean first = false;
        long startWhen = 0;

        while (!eosReceived) {
            if (isInput) {
                int inputIndex = mDecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
                if (inputIndex >= 0) {
                    // fill inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex] with valid data
                    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputIndex];

                    int sampleSize = mExtractor.readSampleData(inputBuffer, 0);

                    if (mExtractor.advance() && sampleSize > 0) {
                        mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(inputIndex, 0, sampleSize, mExtractor.getSampleTime(), 0);

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "InputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                        mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(inputIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                        isInput = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            int outIndex = mDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);
            switch (outIndex) {
            case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                Log.d(TAG, "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                mDecoder.getOutputBuffers();
                break;

            case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                Log.d(TAG, "INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED format : " + mDecoder.getOutputFormat());
                break;

            case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
//              Log.d(TAG, "INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER");
                break;

            default:
                if (!first) {
                    startWhen = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    first = true;
                }
                try {
                    long sleepTime = (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startWhen);
                    Log.d(TAG, "info.presentationTimeUs : " + (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000) + " playTime: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startWhen) + " sleepTime : " + sleepTime);

                    if (sleepTime > 0)
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

                mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true /* Surface init */);
                break;
            }

            // All decoded frames have been rendered, we can stop playing now
            if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "OutputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                break;
            }
        }

        mDecoder.stop();
        mDecoder.release();
        mExtractor.release();
    }

    public void close() {
        eosReceived = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I finally found out why it is causing the audio mute. It was because the mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder) was declared in surfacedCreated() method, and while decoding the video it tries to use surface again (mDecoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0). It is causing overlap issue.